# python yapsy not working

Tags: python-2.7, plugins

I have a problem using the plugin manager for python yapsy(http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/)

I have made a test project with 3 files:

**test.py**

```
from yapsy.PluginManager import PluginManager

manager = PluginManager()
manager.setPluginPlaces(["plugins"])
manager.collectPlugins()

for plugin in manager.getAllPlugins():
    plugin.plugin_object.print_name()
```

**plugins/plugin.py**

```
from yapsy.IPlugin import IPlugin

class Plugin(IPlugin):
    def print_name(self):
        print 'Plugin one'
```

**plugins/plugin.yapsy-plugin**

```
[Core]
Name = Magic_plugin
Module = plugin

[Documentation]
Author = Mario
Version = 1.0
```

But when i start the `test.py`, it says:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "yapsy"
```

Any ideas? I have tried to get the logger using the logger module, but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
from yapsy.IPlugin import IPlugin

class Plugin(IPlugin):
    def print_name(self):
        print 'Plugin one'
```

Note the ':' after class and function

Comment: It was a copy/paste mistake, it still not working for me

Comment: Ok, I thought it could be the problem since I was getting the exact same error message. Could you add your python and yapsy versions? I'm using python 2.7 in a virtualenv with Yapsy 1.11.223. Hope this help

Comment: I have fixed, it was a mistake with the paths, just add the lines for enabled the logger, i have fixed.
Another speed question, do you know how to read a plugin config string inside a plugin?